# Why Android studio is giving error after implementing 'constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use Android Motion layout and for that implemented `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1`

but during build time I'm getting this error.

I've already tried downgrading to the alph4 version of constraintlayout

> Android resource compilation failed
>   E:\Users\avinash91625\StudioProjects\StanBuzzAndroid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeFreemiumDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5753: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/circleRadius' with config ''.
>   E:\Users\avinash91625\StudioProjects\StanBuzzAndroid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeFreemiumDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5753: error: resource previously defined here.
>   E:\Users\avinash91625\StudioProjects\StanBuzzAndroid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeFreemiumDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: error: file failed to compile.

My app gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.stanbuzz.android'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionName '1.17'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode 17
        renderscriptTargetApi 25
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    freemium {
        dimension = 'release'
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionCode = 21
    }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'release'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.msg91.sendotp.library:library:3.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.algolia:algoliasearch-android:3.26.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'io.smooch:core:5.16.2'
    implementation 'io.smooch:ui:5.16.2'
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:2.1'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.takusemba:spotlight:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.sujithkanna:smileyrating:1.6.8'
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.ncorti:slidetoact:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.canner:android-stepsview:1.2'
    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
     // Temporary fix begin
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.2-alpha01'
    // Temporary fix end
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

E:\Users\avinash91625\StudioProjects\StanBuzzAndroid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeFreemiumDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="orange">#fffaaa00</color>
    <color name="primary">#03A9F4</color>
    <color name="white">#fff</color>
    <color name="yellow">#ffff981e</color>
    <declare-styleable name="StepsView"><attr format="integer" name="numOfSteps"/><attr format="integer" name="completePosition"/><attr format="reference" name="labels"/><attr format="reference" name="barColor"/><attr format="reference" name="progressColor"/><attr format="reference" name="labelColor"/><attr format="reference" name="progressTextColor"/><attr format="boolean" name="hideProgressText"/><attr format="float" name="labelSize"/><attr format="float" name="progressMargin"/><attr format="float" name="circleRadius"/><attr format="float" name="progressStrokeWidth"/></declare-styleable>
    <string name="app_name">StepsView</string>
</resources>
```

I think this library is causing this issue - [new AndroidX support](https://github.com/chilijung/android-stepsview/issues/7)

Comment: Delete your build folder, invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Hi @sanjeev, I just did that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Avinash, Have you clean and build/ Invalidate Cache the project? If so this resource compilation error means that there are two resources sharing the same properties. In simple terms, you should remove `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` 
before you import `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1`. Hope this helpled

Comment: Yes, I tried clean and build the project but steel no results and I also don't see another duplicate implementation in my app gradle file, I've included it in the edit.

Comment: @AvinashKumar, Can you share this file,  E:\Users\avinash91625\StudioProjects\StanBuzzAndroid\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeFreemiumDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:5753. Probably the issue is around this file. Check the resource attr/circleRadius, have you declared this twice in the values.xml?

Comment: Ya sure, i've added in the edit. But i haven't used attr/circleRadius anywhere in my project, it seems non-project file and is giving warning for the same when i tried to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using androidx library as well as the support library

**support libraries**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

remove unwanted support library and replace with the corresponding androidx library.

For Artifact mappings see [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#artifact_mappings)

Comment: I tried replacing them with corresponding androidx but didn't work, i think it more have to do with that conflicting StepView library

Comment: @AvinashKumar  are you enabled `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in your `gradle.properties` file ?